# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'indexno11' in 'where clause'

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, swing

tu.java

```
//jdbc connection
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/st","root","root");
//query
    String query = "select indexno,lname,fname from reg where indexno= ? and tel=?";
                
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
                
    ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(in.getText()));
    ps.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(tl.getText()));
                
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                
    if(rs.next()) {
        String name11 =rs.getString("lname");
        String name1 =rs.getString("fname");
        int indexno11 =rs.getInt("indexno");
```

//passing value to wt frame

```
        wt wt = new wt(name11, name1, indexno11);
        wt.show();
    }
            
    rs.close();
    con.close();`
```

wt.java

loging page index number used to check next frame credentials

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/st","root","root");
        String query = "select age from reg where  indexno=indexno11";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()) {
            String age11 =rs.getString("age");
            System.out.println(age11);
        }
        rs.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Your second query needs to contain a placeholder (`?`) instead of placing the String `indexno11` directly into the query. The fill the placeholder with the `setInt` method just as you do with your first query.

Comment: *`select age from reg where  indexno=indexno11`* - in this SQL code both `indexno` and `indexno11` are columns names. If `indexno11` is a value then you must enclose it with quote chars: `select age from reg where  indexno='indexno11'`. If this is a variable name which contains needed value then see the above comment.

Comment: indexno11 is store the first sql indexno columns data and it passing to the secound file sql query to check if indexno = indexno11?

Comment: when i put quotes there nothing happening

Answer (score 0):

You forgot your literalising single quotes around the value in the String query line.

```
String query = "select age from reg where  indexno='indexno11'";
```

Comment: indexno11 is not value it passing previous value to new frame

Comment: Then "you need to explain this much better", because your error indicates you are asking one column to "equal another (whole)" column , when i believe you (probably) would want all "fields" that are the same in either columns rows by a value stipulated to the query, or a comparison of each row to the other row for identical value.

Comment: ju.java files Strung query ="select indexno, fname, lname from ref where indexno='?' & phone='?' ;  then the select indexno passing to int indexno11 variable then the passed indexno11 variable I using to check String query=" select age from reg where indexno='indexno11'

Comment: You are saying indexno11 is actually a variable NOT  a String. ="+indexno11